# Create a weighted graph from a continous text

Tags: nlp, visualization, text-mining, graphs

My goal: plot a graph that shows how much the words of a large text are connected to each other.

My idea is that the closer the range between words, somehow affected by the occurence, the more connected the words are in the text.

I browsed the web for quite some time and noticed that there is a vast amount of algorithms and techniques in the field of text mining. It seems like i can't find a way to start without a deep study of all these topics and i need someone that can point me in the right direction.

my naive approach would be to calculate the distance of every word to any other word and somehow create a graph with weighted distances out of it but this seems like a pretty uncomputable task. Well i know there must be better solutions out there.

Thank you for any suggestions.